# Javascript arrays email substring into full name, firstname and lastname

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, substring

```
      I know my questions are similar to other questions but I could not figure it.
```

I am practicing javascript. I have arrays of emails. from that email I want to get three out puts  of strings fullname, firstname and lastname inside one map function. I can able to get output first name by reading one stack-overflow questions. I am able get full name by I get output `john.doe`, I want `johndoe`. Could not figure it out last name `doe`.

My example email address is like this:  `john.doe@co.uk`

My expected output is

firstname: 'john'

fullname: `johndoe`

lastname: `doe`

**This is my code**

```
const Names = (emails) => {
  emails.map(i => {
    console.log("firstname", i.substring(0, i.indexOf(".")));
    console.log("fullname", i.substring(0, i.lastIndexOf("@")));
    console.log("lastname");
  })
};

Names(emails)
```

```js
const emails = [
  "peter.pittman@taitos.com",
  "ayden.reed@starkindustries.ss",
  "kiefer.franks@amazonia.hk",
  "oz.mcguire@tortelloni.zw",
  "ellisandro.noble@bluthhousing.party",
  "alyas.briggs@taitos.ninja",
  "windsor.raymond@hungryhungyhippopottumoses.co.uk",
  "daniyal.brock@hungryhungyhippopottumoses.ug",
  "samatar.benson@duffbeer.org",
  "jaime.freeman@gringottsbank.li",
  "aaron.pace@starkindustries.org",
  "guerin.mcgowan@taitos.li",
  "believe.cote@virtucon.hk",
  "abdalroof.ray@oscorp.co.uk",
  "blake.barrett@tortelloni.org",
  "bradlie.brooks@dundermifflin.ug",
  "rayyan.garza@tortelloni.ug",
  "declan.wood@dundermifflin.ug",
  "tymon.blackburn@oscorp.com",
  "joash.duffy@wonkaindustries.ug",
  "aleksander.ford@umbrellacorporation.fi",
  "jaida.colon@macrosloft.se",
  "jevan.jensen@lospolloshermanos.zw",
  "abubakar.palmer@dundermifflin.org",
  "cator.joyce@lospolloshermanos.org",
  "valen.henry@gringottsbank.co.uk",
  "taylor-jay.blackburn@wonkaindustries.ug",
  "leonardo.mcfadden@goldenstatuettes.co.uk",
  "noel.schneider@hungryhungyhippopottumoses.co.uk",
  "will.osborne@tasavallanpresidentti.com",
  "arda.aguilar@oscorp.fi",
  "omri.walls@virtucon.ug",
  "lliam.briggs@tortelloni.se",
  "kris.lester@amazonia.fi",
  "skye.soto@wonkaindustries.se",
  "dermot.vang@goldenstatuettes.com",
  "cruiz.simmons@cookykitchens.co.uk",
  "tymoteusz.riley@tortelloni.fi",
  "kaidyn.hays@aperaturescience.party",
  "apisai.fletcher@oscorp.co.uk",
  "kedrick.mcfadden@cookykitchens.com",
  "archibald.elliott@gringottsbank.hk",
  "kjae.hurley@umbrellacorporation.com",
  "tymon.nielsen@hungryhungyhippopottumoses.fi",
  "james.dejesus@amazonia.party",
  "reno.silva@gringottsbank.ug",
  "tayyib.brooks@taitos.ss",
  "cormack.alexander@duffbeer.ss",
  "obieluem.guerra@umbrellacorporation.party",
  "hector.moran@dundermifflin.co.uk",
  "logan.parrish@wonkaindustries.com",
  "robin.rivers@starkindustries.zw",
  "albie.spence@tasavallanpresidentti.hk",
  "qasim.schwartz@duffbeer.zw",
  "aodhan.cooper@tasavallanpresidentti.org",
  "eassan.hobbs@lospolloshermanos.org",
  "parkash.juarez@wonkaindustries.party",
  "teos.horton@haxhoont.se",
  "kuba.larsen@duffbeer.ninja",
  "eisa.beard@umbrellacorporation.li",
  "hamza.french@starkindustries.org",
  "sung.randall@taitos.ss",
  "samir.bond@virtucon.org",
  "conlyn.mckee@goldenstatuettes.com",
  "thiago.hooper@starkindustries.com",
  "demetrius.holland@macrosloft.zw",
  "uchenna.oneill@hungryhungyhippopottumoses.zw",
  "windsor.steele@hungryhungyhippopottumoses.fi",
  "keiryn.macias@tasavallanpresidentti.org",
  "kehinde.allen@cookykitchens.hk",
  "yuri.ramirez@macrosloft.zw",
  "ruan.perez@umbrellacorporation.org",
  "dyllon.young@dundermifflin.zw",
  "lockey.mcmahon@goldenstatuettes.fi",
  "lyndsay.haynes@goldenstatuettes.ninja",
  "dareh.grimes@macrosloft.co.uk",
  "veeran.vinson@cookykitchens.fi",
  "jayke.schroeder@lospolloshermanos.org",
  "aronas.berry@bluthhousing.li",
  "jonothan.donaldson@gringottsbank.zw",
  "kenzeigh.weber@umbrellacorporation.se",
  "cesare.huber@tasavallanpresidentti.com",
  "uzair.harris@virtucon.ninja",
  "kelan.yates@taitos.co.uk",
  "thomson.gonzales@bluthhousing.co.uk",
  "keaton.green@umbrellacorporation.hk",
  "jazeb.kinney@duffbeer.co.uk",
  "ronald.flores@starkindustries.hk",
  "alastair.moses@umbrellacorporation.se",
  "ogheneochuko.ratliff@aperaturescience.se",
  "kenton.conley@gringottsbank.ninja",
  "kashif.trujillo@bluthhousing.hk",
  "saghun.ayers@taitos.hk",
  "kamil.eaton@lospolloshermanos.org",
  "bailee.henson@goldenstatuettes.li",
  "alexei.stanton@haxhoont.li",
  "basher.clarke@taitos.li",
]



const Names = (emails) => {
  emails.map(i => {
    console.log("firstname", i.substring(0, i.indexOf(".")));
    console.log("fullname", i.substring(0, i.lastIndexOf("@")));
    console.log("lastname");
  })
};

Names(emails)
```

Comment: see the docs of `split`

Comment: split returns array. I want each of them as strings

Comment: `split('@')[0].split('.')` use arr[index] can get it's value :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use replace to remove '.'.

lastname can be get in substring between '.' and '@'

```js
const emails = [
  "peter.pittman@taitos.com",
  "ayden.reed@starkindustries.ss",
  "kiefer.franks@amazonia.hk",
  "oz.mcguire@tortelloni.zw",
  "ellisandro.noble@bluthhousing.party",
  "alyas.briggs@taitos.ninja",
  "windsor.raymond@hungryhungyhippopottumoses.co.uk",
  "daniyal.brock@hungryhungyhippopottumoses.ug",
  "samatar.benson@duffbeer.org",
  "jaime.freeman@gringottsbank.li",
  "aaron.pace@starkindustries.org",
  "guerin.mcgowan@taitos.li",
  "believe.cote@virtucon.hk",
  "abdalroof.ray@oscorp.co.uk",
  "blake.barrett@tortelloni.org",
  "bradlie.brooks@dundermifflin.ug",
  "rayyan.garza@tortelloni.ug",
  "declan.wood@dundermifflin.ug",
  "tymon.blackburn@oscorp.com",
  "joash.duffy@wonkaindustries.ug",
  "aleksander.ford@umbrellacorporation.fi",
  "jaida.colon@macrosloft.se",
  "jevan.jensen@lospolloshermanos.zw",
  "abubakar.palmer@dundermifflin.org",
  "cator.joyce@lospolloshermanos.org",
  "valen.henry@gringottsbank.co.uk",
  "taylor-jay.blackburn@wonkaindustries.ug",
  "leonardo.mcfadden@goldenstatuettes.co.uk",
  "noel.schneider@hungryhungyhippopottumoses.co.uk",
  "will.osborne@tasavallanpresidentti.com",
  "arda.aguilar@oscorp.fi",
  "omri.walls@virtucon.ug",
  "lliam.briggs@tortelloni.se",
  "kris.lester@amazonia.fi",
  "skye.soto@wonkaindustries.se",
  "dermot.vang@goldenstatuettes.com",
  "cruiz.simmons@cookykitchens.co.uk",
  "tymoteusz.riley@tortelloni.fi",
  "kaidyn.hays@aperaturescience.party",
  "apisai.fletcher@oscorp.co.uk",
  "kedrick.mcfadden@cookykitchens.com",
  "archibald.elliott@gringottsbank.hk",
  "kjae.hurley@umbrellacorporation.com",
  "tymon.nielsen@hungryhungyhippopottumoses.fi",
  "james.dejesus@amazonia.party",
  "reno.silva@gringottsbank.ug",
  "tayyib.brooks@taitos.ss",
  "cormack.alexander@duffbeer.ss",
  "obieluem.guerra@umbrellacorporation.party",
  "hector.moran@dundermifflin.co.uk",
  "logan.parrish@wonkaindustries.com",
  "robin.rivers@starkindustries.zw",
  "albie.spence@tasavallanpresidentti.hk",
  "qasim.schwartz@duffbeer.zw",
  "aodhan.cooper@tasavallanpresidentti.org",
  "eassan.hobbs@lospolloshermanos.org",
  "parkash.juarez@wonkaindustries.party",
  "teos.horton@haxhoont.se",
  "kuba.larsen@duffbeer.ninja",
  "eisa.beard@umbrellacorporation.li",
  "hamza.french@starkindustries.org",
  "sung.randall@taitos.ss",
  "samir.bond@virtucon.org",
  "conlyn.mckee@goldenstatuettes.com",
  "thiago.hooper@starkindustries.com",
  "demetrius.holland@macrosloft.zw",
  "uchenna.oneill@hungryhungyhippopottumoses.zw",
  "windsor.steele@hungryhungyhippopottumoses.fi",
  "keiryn.macias@tasavallanpresidentti.org",
  "kehinde.allen@cookykitchens.hk",
  "yuri.ramirez@macrosloft.zw",
  "ruan.perez@umbrellacorporation.org",
  "dyllon.young@dundermifflin.zw",
  "lockey.mcmahon@goldenstatuettes.fi",
  "lyndsay.haynes@goldenstatuettes.ninja",
  "dareh.grimes@macrosloft.co.uk",
  "veeran.vinson@cookykitchens.fi",
  "jayke.schroeder@lospolloshermanos.org",
  "aronas.berry@bluthhousing.li",
  "jonothan.donaldson@gringottsbank.zw",
  "kenzeigh.weber@umbrellacorporation.se",
  "cesare.huber@tasavallanpresidentti.com",
  "uzair.harris@virtucon.ninja",
  "kelan.yates@taitos.co.uk",
  "thomson.gonzales@bluthhousing.co.uk",
  "keaton.green@umbrellacorporation.hk",
  "jazeb.kinney@duffbeer.co.uk",
  "ronald.flores@starkindustries.hk",
  "alastair.moses@umbrellacorporation.se",
  "ogheneochuko.ratliff@aperaturescience.se",
  "kenton.conley@gringottsbank.ninja",
  "kashif.trujillo@bluthhousing.hk",
  "saghun.ayers@taitos.hk",
  "kamil.eaton@lospolloshermanos.org",
  "bailee.henson@goldenstatuettes.li",
  "alexei.stanton@haxhoont.li",
  "basher.clarke@taitos.li",
]



const Names = (emails) => {
  emails.map(i => {
    console.log("firstname:", i.substring(0, i.indexOf(".")),
                ", fullname:", i.substring(0, i.lastIndexOf("@")).replace(".", ""),
                ", lastname:", i.substring(i.indexOf(".")+1, i.lastIndexOf("@")));
  })
};

Names(emails)
```

Answer (score 1):

For fullname, you cane use `replace(".", "")` to remove the '.'
So for fullname it can be:
`i.substring(0, i.lastIndexOf("@")).replace(".", "")`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```js
const Names = (emails) => {
  emails.forEach(i => {
    const indexDot = i.indexOf(".");
    const indexAt = i.lastIndexOf("@");
    console.log("firstname", i.substring(0, indexDot));
    console.log("fullname", i.substring(0, indexAt));
    console.log("lastname", i.substring(indexDot+1, indexAt));
  })
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#map` with `string#split` to get names.

```js
const emails = [ "peter.pittman@taitos.com", "ayden.reed@starkindustries.ss", "kiefer.franks@amazonia.hk", "oz.mcguire@tortelloni.zw", "ellisandro.noble@bluthhousing.party", "alyas.briggs@taitos.ninja", "windsor.raymond@hungryhungyhippopottumoses.co.uk", "daniyal.brock@hungryhungyhippopottumoses.ug", "samatar.benson@duffbeer.org", "jaime.freeman@gringottsbank.li", "aaron.pace@starkindustries.org", "guerin.mcgowan@taitos.li", "believe.cote@virtucon.hk", "abdalroof.ray@oscorp.co.uk", "blake.barrett@tortelloni.org", "bradlie.brooks@dundermifflin.ug", "rayyan.garza@tortelloni.ug", "declan.wood@dundermifflin.ug", "tymon.blackburn@oscorp.com", "joash.duffy@wonkaindustries.ug", "aleksander.ford@umbrellacorporation.fi", "jaida.colon@macrosloft.se", "jevan.jensen@lospolloshermanos.zw", "abubakar.palmer@dundermifflin.org", "cator.joyce@lospolloshermanos.org", "valen.henry@gringottsbank.co.uk", "taylor-jay.blackburn@wonkaindustries.ug", "leonardo.mcfadden@goldenstatuettes.co.uk", "noel.schneider@hungryhungyhippopottumoses.co.uk", "will.osborne@tasavallanpresidentti.com","arda.aguilar@oscorp.fi", "omri.walls@virtucon.ug", "lliam.briggs@tortelloni.se", "kris.lester@amazonia.fi", "skye.soto@wonkaindustries.se", "dermot.vang@goldenstatuettes.com", "cruiz.simmons@cookykitchens.co.uk"],
    users = emails.map(mail => {
      const [fullName] =  mail.split('@');
      const [firstName, lastName] = fullName.split('.');
      return { fullName: `${firstName}${lastName}`, firstName, lastName };
    });
console.log(users);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I want string  output like this `john`, `doe`, `johndoe`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const emails=["peter.pittman@taitos.com","ayden.reed@starkindustries.ss","kiefer.franks@amazonia.hk","oz.mcguire@tortelloni.zw","ellisandro.noble@bluthhousing.party","alyas.briggs@taitos.ninja","windsor.raymond@hungryhungyhippopottumoses.co.uk","daniyal.brock@hungryhungyhippopottumoses.ug"]

let re = /^(?<first>\w+)\.(?<second>\w+)@/

let result = emails.map(e => {
    let {first,second} = e.match(re).groups
    return {fulll:first+second,first,second}
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the email addressed can contain other characters than only word characters, and you want to check if there are characters after the `@` as well for the full format, you might also use a pattern like:

```
^([^\s@.]+)\.([^\s@.]+)@[^\s@]+$
```

Then pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `([^\s@.]+)` Capture **group 1**, Match any char other than a whitespace char, `@` or `.`
- `\.` Match a dot
- `([^\s@.]+)` Capture **group 2**, Match any char other than a whitespace char, `@` or `.`
- `@[^\s@]+` Match the `@` followed by 1 or more chars other than `@`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sdpcaY/1)

In the code, check if there is a match and use the 2 capture groups. If there is not match, leave the string as is to not get undefined or unexpected behaviour.

```js
const emails = ["peter.pittman@taitos.com", "peter@taitos.com"]
let regex = /^([^\s@.]+)\.([^\s@.]+)@[^\s@]+$/

let result = emails.map(s => {
  let m = s.match(regex);
  if (m) {
    return {
      "fullname": m[1] + m[2],
      "firstname": m[1],
      "lastname": m[2]
    }
  }
  return s;
})

console.log(result)
```